# how can get deletion or insertion notify realm inner list?

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

i have ticket class and message class like below.
i want set change listener just for inner message list in special ticket id  no whole table message.
i read about result and object changeListener and  Notifications but i can't find any solution ;

how can I do that ?

```
public class TicketPojo extends RealmObject {

private Date createAt;
private Date updateAt;
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String supporterName;
private int supporterID;
RealmList<MessagePojo> messages;
 //....
 }
```

and

```
public class MessagePojo extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
int id;
String messageType;
String Message;
Date createAt;
Date updateAt;
//...
}
```

Comment: you can use Livedata with observer.

Comment: You need to add a RealmChangeListener to `messages`. You must also keep `messages` as a field reference.